# Dreamhost Email Settings for Django

Tags: django, email

I have tried a variety of different settings for my email to work on my django app. My server is on dreamhost. I cannot get it to send/receive

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.domain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Tried user id, password, to, from etc. Nothing seems to work. Anyone have success or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the error in debug mode when you try to send email.

Comment: thats the thing. There is no error showing. Says message was sent. Debug is on.